# UnicodeEncodeError in python 3 in eclipse editor

Tags: python, eclipse, utf-8, error-handling, python-unicode

I have a strange problem in reading a file with saved utf-8 format (It's saved by Persian language). I use from eclipse luna and write the following code to read from my file and show it in internal console of eclipse. when I use the following code I didn't see the correct word:

```
f = open('myfile.txt', 'r')
for i in f:
    print(i)
```

I got this result in internal console:

```
ï»¿Ø³Ù„Ø§Ù… ØºÙ„Ø§Ù… Ø±Ø¶Ø§

Ú†Ø·ÙˆØ±Ù†ÛŒØŸ
```

But I want to see it in Persian, so I used from the following code:

```
f = open('myfile.txt', 'r', encoding = 'utf_8')
for i in f:
    print(i)
```

when I run this, I got this error and couldn't solve it anymore:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\Msn Folder\92\Python\Projects\PythonSamplesByMsn\00 Python       Preliminary\test2.py", line 4, in <module>
print(i)
File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
 UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-4:     character maps to <undefined>
```

I have searched for them in stack overflow and also many sites in internet but I couldn't solve it. 
How can I solve it and see Persian words as an output in console?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `utf-8`, not `utf_8`?

Comment: @Kasra: this isn't a reading issue, this is a **printing** issue.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yeah in python 3 both work, but yes its because of the console! i missed that the console is eclipse!

Comment: Thanks, I got my problem and I could solve it in eclipse. Many thanks for your support